# how to delete Packages in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Can we delete packages in salesforce or remove certain fields which have been referenced there?

I created a package couple of months ago and the `changeset` had certain fields which are part of an App  Exchange Package. And I am unable to uninstall the package from my Sandbox?

Can someone help?

Comment: Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, check How to Ask to make your post answerable https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall managed packages, but you can't selectively remove certain fields.

This link should take you to the page to uninstall the package:
https://ap4.salesforce.com/0A3?setupid=ImportedPackage
You might need to change the "ap4" to your org's instance id.

When you uninstall the package, the data will be deleted (although there is an option to save it for a short period of time). It might be best to make a backup of any data you might need later before uninstalling.